# create a function to add a doubly linked list to itself at the end

Tags: c++, struct, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Node{
public:
double data;
Node* next;
Node* prev;
};
void insert(Node**,int);
void display(Node*);
void finaloutput(Node*,Node**);
int main()
{
    Node* head=NULL;
    Node** second=NULL;
    insert(&head,1);
    insert(&head,2);
    insert(&head,3);
    insert(&head,4);
    insert(&head,5);
    cout<<"List is"<<endl;
    display(head);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Final output is"<<endl;
    second=&head;
//  Node* second=(*&head);
finaloutput(head,second);
display(head);
}
void insert(Node** headref,int new_data)
{
Node* new_node=new Node();
new_node->data=new_data;
new_node->next=(*headref);
new_node->prev=NULL;
if(*headref!=NULL)
{
(*headref)->prev=new_node;
}
(*headref)=new_node;
}
void display(Node* headref)
{
Node* temp=headref;
while (temp!=NULL)
{
    cout<<temp->data<<" ";
    temp=temp->next;
}

}
void finaloutput(Node* headref,Node** second)
{  
Node ptrbegin;
Node* temp=(headref);
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
    temp=temp->next;
}

temp->next=(*second);
}
```

I want to create a function to add a link list to itself at end but in this after `temp->next=(*second)` this end up showing an infinite loop. I tried to get only value copy of `Node* head` as `second` but it didn't help. Please giude me with example code in c++.

the output that i want is like
'5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1'

Comment: You need to add some condition in your ```display``` function to stop, because if you link the last node with the first, it is a circular list and ```while (temp!=NULL)``` in ```display``` will always return ```true``` hence the infinite loop. Also, I don't understand the desired output, where the additional "4" on the middle comes from?

Comment: @Arsam Javed Why is there three numbers 4 in this expected output 5 4 3 2 1 4 5 4 3 2 1?

Comment: sorry my mistake now it is corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assignment is

> create a function to add a doubly linked list to itself at the end

then the expected by you output

```
5 4 3 2 1 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

is incorrect because before doubling the list it has the following values

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

So the output of the doubled list will be

```
5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1
```

You need to add new nodes to the list with copies of currently stored data.

The data member `data` of your class `Node` is declared with the type specifier `double`

```
class Node{
public:
double data;
Node* next;
Node* prev;
};
```

However the function `insert` deals with data of the type `int`

```
void insert(Node**,int);
```

So you need to change either the type of the data member or the type of the parameter. There is no great sense to use the class key `class` instead of the class key `struct`. Also as the program is a C++ program then you should pass the pointer to the head node by reference in the C++ meaning instead of the C meaning through a pointer to pointer.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function `finaloutput` that I renamed in the program to `double_list` can be written.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

void insert( Node * &head, int data )
{
    head = new Node { data, head, nullptr };
    if ( head->next ) head->next->prev = head;
}

std::ostream & display( const Node * head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const Node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }
    
    return os << "null";
}

void double_list( Node * &head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        Node *second_head = nullptr;
        
        Node **first = &head;

        for ( Node **second = &second_head, *prev = nullptr; 
              *first;
              first = &( *first )->next, prev = *second, second = &( *second )->next ) 
        {
            *second = new Node { ( *first )->data, nullptr, prev };
        }
        
        *first = second_head;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    
    insert( head, 1 );
    insert( head, 2 );
    insert( head, 3 );
    insert( head, 4 );
    insert( head, 5 );

    display( head ) << '\n';
    
    double_list( head );
    
    display( head ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null
```